# json .makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",params) ignoring the URL parameter with multiple calls? Android / PHP web service issue

Tags: java, php, android, json

I've got a `PHP` web service and am querying it to populate the user interface. I have an issue where `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",params);` is ignoring the URL passed to it and is instead running the query against the last used PHP URL.

My web services are [this](http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/menuitems.php?) and [this](http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/test.php?)

To replicate this, search for 'EF' in editext1 and press the button. Then, delete the 'F' from the end of edittext1. The LayoutSpinner will fill up with 101 entries of 'Civic' 'Hatch' 'Civic' 'Hatch' because it has queried the test.php web service instead of menuitems.php.

URL string is being set by `setOnItemSelectedListener` which triggers whenever any of the spinner controls change. It then fires the background task LoadAllProducts to query the web service. I've confirmed that the URL string is pointing to menuitems.php when the `jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",params)` line runs by using breakpoints and watching variables. Has anyone else run into this issue before and what route should I go down to fix it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
        // view products click event
        btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)              
                // Execute LoadAllProducts
                url =  "http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/test.php";
                new LoadAllProducts().execute();                        
            }


        // listener for EditText1 changes.
             @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                chassiscode = v.getText().toString(); //put the chassiscode into a global           variable.
                url =  "http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/menuitems.php";
                new LoadAllProducts().execute();
            }


    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  {


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("chassiscode",chassiscode));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Civic", model));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("layout", layout));               

            // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
         // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",params);

                products = json.getJSONArray("components");
                productslist.clear(); //clear the productslist and start from scratch.



                    // looping through All Products

                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(url == "http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/test.php") {
                        //if components are being retrieved 


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productslist.add(c.getString("ComponentName"));


                        } else if (url == "http://www.jankuyado.com/Components/menuitems.php") {
                        //else if menu items are being retrieved.   
                            // Storing each json item in the productslist

                            if  (c.has("model")) {
                                MenuReturnType = "model"; //flag global variable MenuReturnType as returning car Models (used later when parsing the Productlist).
                                productslist.add(c.getString("model"));                                                             
                            }

                            if  (c.has("layout")) {
                                MenuReturnType = "layout"; //flag global variable MenuReturnType as returning car Layouts (used later when parsing the Productlist).
                                productslist.add(c.getString("layout"));
                            }


                        }
                    }
            }


            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
           //stuff that updates ui here
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend distilling your code WAY down to a specific, relevant example, rather than just pasting in your entire Activity code. Not many people are going to want to search through the whole thing for the relevant bits. It will also force you to think about your question more creatively, during which you may find an answer presents itself. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'll distill it down and come back. Might even figure it out :)

Comment: I have just distilled the code down to just the relevant parts, but I couldn't figure out why it was malfunctioning :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The JSONParser class was getting some junk data back from the .php query under certain conditions. When this happened for some reason the JSONParser returned the last successful JSON query output instead of null. Once I fixed this and made my code handle a null JSONArray return everything worked properly.

Comment: i have a similar problem....the http request wont recognize http://www.blablabla.com/getScores.php?country=us, but will recognize..http://www.blablabla.com/getScores.php...any ideas?????notice(?country=us)...